# How to get the right width and height value use jWindowCrop.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, crop

When use the jWindowCrop.js to crop the image, I can get the right X,Y,W,H value if I don't change the picture. If I change to another picture, the W, H value will be the same value of the first picture.

**HTML:**

```
<img id="target3" class="crop_me" alt="" src="http://www.wallpapersam.com/wallpapers/2014/02/Adriana-Boat-In-Portofino-Italy-  1200x1920.jpg" />
<div id="results">
    <b>X</b>: <span id="crop_x"></span><br />
    <b>Y</b>: <span id="crop_y"></span><br />
    <b>W</b>: <span id="crop_w"></span><br />
    <b>H</b>: <span id="crop_h"></span><br />
</div>
<button id="setUrlToNull">Set src to null</button>
<button id="setUrlToNewPic">Set src to another picture</button>
```

**Javascript:**

```
    $(function() {
        $('.crop_me').jWindowCrop({
            targetWidth: 400,
            targetHeight: 300,
            loadingText: '',
            onChange: function(result) {
                $('#crop_x').text(result.cropX);
                $('#crop_y').text(result.cropY);
                $('#crop_w').text(result.cropW);
                $('#crop_h').text(result.cropH);
            }
        });
    });

   $('#setUrlToNull').click(function() {
       $('#target3').attr("src", '');
    });

    $('#setUrlToNewPic').click(function() {
        $('#target3').attr("src", 'https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/431568655512383488/xjwn1J6J.jpeg');
    });
```

You can see my code here:

http://jsfiddle.net/dA25D/

If you click the set src to null button and then click the set src to another picture, you will see that the X,Y,W,H value is different from the right one.

I want to get the right X,Y,W,H value after I changed the picture, what is the right way to do this?

Comment: Seems like a bug to me, I would try to make a issue in a github.

Comment: @MaunoV. Thanks. Do you know any other library which can crop image like this one?

Comment: No, havent used much of those myself .. maybe you should look the list of http://www.jqueryrain.com/demo/jquery-crop-image-plugin/ Tbh. the one you used doesn't seem that popular.